# Fail fast flag for rspec 1.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

As far as I know there is a --fail-fast flag in Rspec2 to stop running test execution whenever it fails:

```
rspec spec/ --fail-fast
```

Apparently this flag does not exist in Rspec1:

```
spec spec/ --fail-fast
invalid option: --fail-fast (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

Any hint?

Comment: This option was added in `rspec 2.1`

Comment: Jep, there seems to be nothing similar in rspec 1.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mention in my comment `fail-fast` option was added on rspec 2.1 version.
The closest behavior to what you want to achieve are gems like [rspec-instafail](https://github.com/grosser/rspec-instafail) or [fuubar](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar).